# Estou tendo problemas com MySQL, nao sei como tirar media

Tags: mysql

Queria saber a media de pedidos pago por boleto na tabela Pagamento, como eu faria isso?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: onde estão os dados da compra? existe outra tabela? você precisa apresentar a estrutura das tabelas ou será impossível resolver o problema

Comment: veja se melhorou

Comment: No título você diz que está com um problema... qual é? O que tentou fazer para calcular a média?

Comment: eu nao sei calcular a media, estou perguntando como faria isso.

Comment: a media de pedidos pago por boleto, eu perguntei ali em cima como faria isso, eu nao tenho  a mínima ideia de como fazer.

Comment: pago por boleto ou por condição de pagamento ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para calcular a média no `MySQL` utilizamos a função `AVG`.

Desta forma você filtra a forma de pagamento pelo código, que no caso é `6`:

```
SELECT a.`Tipo`, AVG(b.`ValorPagar`) AS media FROM FormaPagamento a
INNER JOIN Pagamento b ON a.`CodigoPagForm` = b.`CodigoFormaPagamento`
WHERE a.`CodigoPagForm` = 6
GROUP BY a.`Tipo`;
```

E desta forma você filtra pelo tipo:

```
SELECT a.`Tipo`, AVG(b.`ValorPagar`) AS media FROM FormaPagamento a
INNER JOIN Pagamento b ON a.`CodigoPagForm` = b.`CodigoFormaPagamento`
WHERE a.`Tipo` = 'Boleto'
GROUP BY a.`Tipo`;
```

Veja mais sobre a função `AVG` [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Comment: muito obrigado, eu nao sabia disso.

Answer (score 4):

Calcula a média :

```
Select codigo, AVG(valor) FROM Tabela
```

Calcula a média com valores destintos:

```
Select codigo, AVG(DISTINCT valor) FROM Tabela
```

Calcula a média e ordena o resultado pelo identificador(id):

```
Select codigo, AVG(valor) from Tabela GROUP BY codigo
```

Calcula a média dos valores destintos e ordena o resultado pelo identificador(id):

```
Select codigo, AVG(DISTINCT valor) from Tabela GROUP BY codigo
```

Exemplo pela [W3sshools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_avg).

Documentação [MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html).